# Finding a growth rate which changes via a stochastic process by integrating

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes

The (continuously compounded) growth rate r as a function of time t has the form:
$$dr(t)=a(b-r(t))dt+c dW(t)$$

Where a, b, c are constants, and W(t) is a standard Wiener process.

The goal is that given a starting value (say $V_0$) and a period of time (say $0$ to $T$), you can model the final value as:

$$ V_T=V_0e^{\int^T_0r(t)dt}$$

I am not sure how to get from the first equation to $r(t)$ (and then I do not know if I could do the integral). So help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating a normally distributed random variable over time.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416393/integrating-a-normally-distributed-random-variable-over-time)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x(t)=e^{a t}r(t)$. Then

$$ dx = e^{a t}(ab \>dt+ cdW_t)
$$

Integrate

$$x(T)=x_0 + ab \int_0^T e^{at}dt +c \int_0^T e^{a t}dW_t
$$

Thus, the solution is

$$r(T)= e^{-aT}r_0+ ab\int_0^T e^{-a(T-t)}dt +c \int_0^T e^{-a(T-t)} dW_t
$$

Comment: How are you getting to each line in your response? Can't seem to replicate it. And the final part of the last line has an integral wrt $dW_t$, which I'm not sure how to evaluate

Comment: @DQd - the last term is a random variable, with normal distribution