# Integrating a normally distributed random variable over time.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, random-variables, normal-distribution

Say $r_t$ is a growth rate at time $t$ which follows the Vasiek model/is normally distributed with:
$$E[r_t]=r_0 e^{-at}+b(1-e^{-at})$$
$$Var[r_t]=({\sigma^2}/{2a}) (1-e^{-2at})$$

Where $a,b,\sigma,r_0$ are constants.

For some constant point in time $T$, what would the solution to this look like?:
$$\int^T_0 r_t dt$$

***Context***

The purpose is to simulate an asset's value at different points in time.
Say an asset has a starting value $V_0$, and I'm interested in getting a distribution of $V_T$ at some point in time $T$.

Assuming the (continuously compounded) growth rate $r_t$ follows the Vasicek model $$r_t=r_0\,e^{-at}+b\,(1-e^{-at})+\sigma\,e^{-at}\int_0^te^{as}\,dW_s$$

The value $V_T$ at a point in time is given as:
$$V_T=V_0 e^{\int^T_0 r_t dt}$$

In this case, $a$ is the speed of reversion, $b$ the expected long-run growth rate of the asset, $\sigma$ defines the volatility, and these are all constants. For simplicity I can also assume that $r_0=b$

At the moment, I'm simulating $V_T$ by using $dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$ but with discrete time steps of 1 year, but would like a more previse continuous distribution.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Usually a normally distributed variable cannot be integrated.

Comment: The asset $V_T$ that you simulate there is a simple money market account that earns you a daily interest of $r_t\,dt$. Usually (but not necessarily) one simulates assets under the risk-neutral measure which means that the expectation of the path wise discount factor $e^{-\int_0^Tr_tdt}$ must agree with a discount factor we know from today's term structure of interest rates. It is well-known in the finance literature that with a constant mean reversion level this can in general not be achieved. What is it that gives you unexpected results ? Unexpected in what sense?

Comment: With 10,000 simulations/draws: [distribution](https://i.imgur.com/r6ghCv6.jpg)

The simulated one has the expected mean after 10 years, whereas the one using the integral does not, and has too many very large values

Comment: Better graph [here](https://i.imgur.com/LEHWF9Q.jpg) but it stops at the max value for using the discrete time simulation. The values using the integral go up to ~13bn so something is wrong.

Comment: Did you take into account that $V_T$ should be written as $V_0e^{\mu + X - {\rm Var}[(*)]/2}$ where $\mu$ and ${\rm Var}[(*)]$ are from my answer and $X$ is normal with that variance?

Comment: I've just been doing $V_T=V_0 e^{X}$ where $X \sim N(\mu,(**))$,  will rerun tomorrow.

Comment: With $V_0=200,000,000, a=0.5, b=0.07, \sigma=0.10, T=10$ and also $r_0=0.07$ but the first growth rate applied with the discrete model is $r_1$. I get the following for the discrete (using $dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$ with 1 year time steps for 10 years), model (1) with $V_T=V_0 e^{X}$ where $X\sim N(\mu,Var[(*)])$ and model (2) $V_T=V_0 e^{\mu+X-0.5Var[(*)]}$: [image](https://i.imgur.com/9DVfOsC.png)

Answer (score 1):

When $r_t$ follows the Vasicek model then
$$
r_t=r_0\,e^{-at}+b\,(1-e^{-at})+\sigma\,e^{-at}\int_0^te^{as}\,dW_s\,.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\int_0^Tr_t\,dt=\underbrace{b\,T+(r_0-b)\frac{1-e^{-aT}}{a}}_{\textstyle=:\mu}+\underbrace{\sigma\int_0^T\int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}\,dW_s\,dt}_{\textstyle(*)}\,.
$$
This is Gaussian with mean $\mu$. To compute the variance we use stochastic Fubini
that gives
\begin{align}
(*)=\sigma\int_0^T\int_s^Te^{-a(t-s)}\,dt\,dW_s=\sigma\int_0^T\frac{1-e^{-a(T-s)}}{a}\,dW_s\,.
\end{align}
The variance of ($*$) and of $\int_0^Tr_t\,dt$ is therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}\underbrace{\int_0^T\Big(1-e^{-a(T-s)}\Big)^2\,ds}_{\textstyle(**)}\,.
\end{align}
This integral evaluates as
$$
(**)=T-2\frac{1-e^{-aT}}{a}+\frac{1-e^{-2aT}}{2a}\,.
$$
When $a=0$ you can easily see that ($*$) becomes
$$
\sigma\int_0^T W_t\,dt=\sigma\int_0^T(T-s)\,dW_s
$$
which has the variance
\begin{align}
\sigma^2\int_0^T(T-s)^2\,ds=\frac{\sigma^2T^3}{3}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, where did the $t$'s in the evaluation of (**) come from?

Comment: Looks like they should be zero. Will check and edit.

Comment: (**) seems correct now. Using this in my model is still giving unexpected results. I'm not familiar with stochastic Fubini but when swapping the order of integration should the limits change as written ($\int^T_0 \int^t_0$ to $\int^T_0 \int^T_s$) or should it be to $\int^t_0 \int^T_0$)?

Comment: Fubini raises always the same question. In (*) we integrate over the triangle $\{0\le s\le t\le T\}$. It might help if you draw a small picture. Regarding the unexpected results. What are you using this model for ? Why is $b$ a constant ? Start new question or edit the above one with details that I can possibly reproduce.

Comment: I have added some more details, let me know if it's enough

Comment: Also, in the case where a=0 the integral can't be evaluated, but a=0 is fine in a discrete simulation.

Comment: @DQd . See edit.